# How to pass URL with tweet in twitter?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I want to send text along with URL as tweet to twitter from my iPhone app and i have used XAuth but don't know how to do that.

Please give your suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple there is no separate methods for that.
Just combine the URL with the Text

```
NSString *tweet = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your Tweet Message http://stackoverflow.com/"];
[engine sendUpdate:tweet];
 //engine is your Twitter Object
```